# Поиск параграфа с длинной равной введеному числу

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько параграфов, обернутых в тег p, есть форма с инпутом. Задача: при введение в инпут числа, находится параграф, длина которого равна введенному числу и этот параграф оборачивается в тег strong. Если нет соответствий - алерт, что совпадений нет. Написал, скрипт, но он почему-то всегда выводит , что нет совпадений.

```
function search(el) {
    return document.querySelector(el);
}

function searchAll(el) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(el);
}

var form = search('.form');

function count() {
    var pp = searchAll('p');
    var inp = search('.input');
    for (i = 0; i < pp.length; i++) {
        var parLen = pp[i].innerText;
        if (Number(inp.value) == parLen.length) {
            pp[i].innerHTML = "<strong>" + parLen + "</strong>";
        } else {
            alert("Совпадений нет!");
            return false
        }
    }
}

form.onsubmit = function () {
    count();
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// При клике на кнопку "Найти"
// Для всех <p> проходимся и проверяем длинну
// Меняем текст на жирный, если указанная длинна совпала

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
  num = document.getElementById('num').value;
  exists = false;
  
  document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(e) {
    // Устанавливаем начальное значение
    e.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    
    if (e.textContent.length == num) {
      e.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      exists = true;
    }
  });

  if (!exists) alert('Совпадений нету');
  // Чтобы не выполнялся редирект
  return false;
};
```

```html
<p>HelloWorld</p><!-- 10 символов -->
<p>Тут тоже красивый текст</p><!-- 23 -->
<p>Какой-то текст</p><!-- 14 -->

<form>
  <input id="num" type="number" value="10">
  <button>Найти</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inp = document.querySelector("input");

inp.addEventListener('input',function(){
  let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  
  paragraphs.forEach(function(e){
    let tmp = e.querySelector("strong");
    if (tmp !== null && tmp !== undefined){
      e.innerHTML = tmp.innerHTML;
    }
    if (e.innerHTML.length === parseInt(inp.value)){
      let temp = e.innerHTML;
      e.innerHTML = "<strong>"+ temp +"</strong>";
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<p>a</p>
<p>aa</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>aaa</p>
<p>aa</p>
<p>aaaa</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>aaa</p>
```